# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" when emitting "input"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have a custom component that takes a v-model object with a id and name, but in that component I make changes depending on users input, but when I try to emit "input" with the changed data to get it back to parent component I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null", any idea why this is? I have declared "value" as a prop and the no matter what I put as data for the input emit I get that error.

Tested several types of data to the input emit. Gone trough the code with breakpoints and can see that it's somewhere along the emit code that it errors out.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add code...

Comment: Please add minimal reproduceable code to understand the issue in more better way.